# Reformatting a Table using CSS for Small Screens - Keeping Columns Together

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table with multiple rows and columns. It works well on large displays, but I'm trying to make it easier to read on phones, and I can easily present the information for small phones by having it one column wide and multiple columns tall. It's important to me to keep the current columns together, else I was thinking setting the  to display:block.

```
<table>
<tr><td>COL 1</td><td>COL 2</td><td>COL 3</td><td>COL 4</td><td>COL 5</td></tr>
<tr><td>COL 1</td><td>COL 2</td><td>COL 3</td><td>COL 4</td><td>COL 5</td></tr>
<tr><td>COL 1</td><td>COL 2</td><td>COL 3</td><td>COL 4</td><td>COL 5</td></tr>
</table>
```

Is there any way I can keep my columns together? I'd like to keep it like:

```
COL 1
COL 1
COL 1
COL 2
COL 2
COL 2
COL 3
COL 3
COL 3
COL 4
COL 4
COL 4
COL 5
COL 5
COL 5
```

Comment: Are the columns a fixed number? Similarly are the rows a fixed number? Is the html set in stone or can you set attributes?

Comment: It's for a weekly schedule, with seven columns for the days of the week, and a variable amount of rows depending on that day's events. The HTML and be modified. Currently there are some colspans for events that cross multiple days.

Comment: Please give a _proper_ example of what you just described in that last comment, and what you want the output to look like for that. _“with seven columns for the days of the week, and a variable amount of rows depending on that day's events”_ - that doesn’t really make sense, you can not have different amounts of rows in different columns of a single table to begin with.

Comment: The only way I can see to do this with css and maintain a table for wider screens is two separate structures and hide and show as appropriate with media queries. The problem with this is duplicate content.

Comment: Thank you @JonP . That's what I was thinking myself, but I was hoping I was wrong and that CSS could be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to drop the `table` tag/structure and you don't need [robust IE Support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) you can do this with [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid)

```css
/*Rugular  7 Wide Grid for wide screen*/
#schedule {
display:grid; 
grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
}

.head {font-weight:bold;}

/*Style for narrow - adjust max-width as needed*/
@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
{

  /*Change to 1 col*/
  #schedule {grid-template-columns:1fr;}
  /*Re order the content*/
  #schedule > :nth-child(7n + 1) {order:1;}
  #schedule > :nth-child(7n + 2) {order:2;}
  #schedule > :nth-child(7n + 3) {order:3;}
  #schedule > :nth-child(7n + 4) {order:4;}
  #schedule > :nth-child(7n + 5) {order:5;}
  #schedule > :nth-child(7n + 6) {order:6;}
  #schedule > :nth-child(7n + 7) {order:7;}
  
  /*Add some spacing to the groups*/
  .head:not(:first-child) {margin-top:0.5em;}
}
```

```html
<div id="schedule">
  <!-- "Header" Row -->
  <div class="head">Mon</div><div class="head">Tues</div><div class="head">Wed</div><div class="head">Thurs</div><div class="head">Fri</div><div class="head">Sat</div><div class="head">Sun</div>
  <!-- First Row -->
  <div>Mon 1</div><div>Tues 1</div><div>Wed 1</div><div>Thurs 1</div><div>Fri 1</div><div >Sat 1</div><div>Sun 1</div>
  <!-- Second Row -->
  <div>Mon 2</div><div>Tues 2</div><div>Wed 2</div><div>Thurs 2</div><div>Fri 2</div><div >Sat 2</div><div>Sun 2</div>
</div>
```